# Magento 2 less compilation error while setup:static-content:deploy and frontend page broken

Tags: magento, less, magento2

Everything was fine, I would make a change, run **`grunt less:sitename`** and the changes would be reflected in the browser. Then all of a sudden I get this...

> > **NameError: variable @modal-popup-breakpoint-screen__m is undefined**

The file which this points to is in the **`Magento_Checkout`** module which I have not touched.

As this is a magento module and has nothing to do with any of my custom code I dont know where to go from here....

Comment: You should read [ask] and make sure you provide a [mcve]. We should be able to start with a vanilla install of Magento, make the same change you made, and then compile to see your error. If we can't do that we can't help you.

Comment: This also just happened to me, did you find what the cause was?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue please let me know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue when we upgrade to **`Magento 2.1.16`**:

I have resolved the issue by adding below changes to the theme

> **1)** ~/app/design/frontend/ThemePackage/theme/web/css/source/**_theme.less**
>   add at line 29: **@import 'components/_modals_extend.less';**
>
> **2)** Add
>   **"components/_modals_extend.less"** folder and file at
>   ~/app/design/frontend/ThemePackage/theme/**web/css/source/**
>
> 3)
>   ~/app/design/frontend/ThemePackage/theme/web/css/source/**components/_modals_extend.less**
>   add at line number 16**:**
>
> **@modal-slide-header__padding-vertical: 2.1rem;**
>   // added from
>   \vendor\magento\magento2-base\lib\web\css\source\components_modals.less
>
> **@modal-popup__padding: 3rem;** // added from
>   \vendor\magento\magento2-base\lib\web\css\source\components_modals.less
>
> **@media-common : false;** //custom from
>   magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-l.less

Here **`ThemePackage/theme`** can be any theme package and theme name.